# Decreasing output fstream

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, fstream, export-to-csv

I'm working with an pressure sensitive LED floor, which outputs its sensors in a 2D array. I want to record this data and send it to a CSV file. However with my current code I gather 300.000 KB per second.

```
void DemoProjectApp::recorddata()
{
    std::ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("datafloor.csv");
    while(pressed = true)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < ProjectSettings::NR_OF_TILES; i++)
        {
            myfile << "Tile" << i << ",";
            myfile << tileIndexToSensorValues[i][0] << ",";
            myfile << tileIndexToSensorValues[i][1] << ",";
            myfile << tileIndexToSensorValues[i][2] << ",";
            myfile << tileIndexToSensorValues[i][3] << "\n";
            myfile.flush();
        }

    }
    if(pressed = false)
    {
        myfile.close();
    }
}
```

Pressed is a boolean changing true or false to start and stop recording.
Does anyone have a solution to decrease the output, but still get the relevant data?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `pressed=true` looks suspicious, but I guess this is pseudocode and you are actually using `==`.

Comment: What do you consider "relevant data"? Do you have some sample rate in mind? If yes, you could either take a sample every `x` milliseconds, or read at a higher rate and take an average so that you end up with the required sample rate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, feeling really stupid but the answer was adding == at the pressed booleans.
Totally overlooked it.

Answer (score 0):

What you're writing there is effectively a series of images. Aka a video file. A video encoded in a very inefficient coding scheme. I guess the pressure field does not have steep changes, so my first approach would be encoding it with a video codec (MPEG4, h264, or such).